# bash, if decimal is greater is working strange

Tags: bash

I have this script to compare `cpuload` is greater then limit `10`.

```
#!/bin/bash

cpuload=$(uptime | cut -d' ' -f 13 | sed '$ s/.$//')
limit=10

echo
echo "cpuload = $cpuload, limit = $limit"
echo

[[ $cpuload > $limit ]] && echo | mail -s "cpuload $cpuload is higher than $limit!" EMAIL
```

Now, I am receiving emails even if value is lower than limit `(3 > 10)`.

Where is the problem?

I tried combinations with condition syntax, but sometimes it is working, sometimes not... I am little confused.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
cpu_load=$(uptime | cut -d' ' -f 13 | sed '$ s/.$//')
limit=1

send_email(){
echo | mail -s "makroczsk, cpuload $cpu_load is higher than limit $limit!" $email_to
}

echo "cpuload = $cpu_load (${cpu_load%%.*}), limit = $limit"

[[ (( ${cpu_load%%.*} > $limit )) ]] && send_email
[[ ${cpu_load%%.*} -gt $limit ]] && send_email
```

```
cpuload = 3.10, limit = 10
./check-cpuload.sh: line 9: [[: 3.10: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".10")
```

And in 1st case, emails are still coming.

**UPDATE 2**

This works. But I am not sure why. `:/`

```
cpu_load=$(uptime | cut -d' ' -f 13 | sed '$ s/.$//')
limit=1

send_email(){
echo | mail -s "makroczsk, cpuload $cpu_load is higher than limit $limit!" $email_to
}

echo "cpuload = $cpu_load (${cpu_load%%.*}), limit = $limit"

#[[ (( ${cpu_load%%.*} > $limit )) ]] && send_email
[[ ${cpu_load%%.*} -gt $limit ]] && send_email
```

Comment: `>` is used for string comparison, use `-gt` for integers. Or use arithmetic expressions with `(( cpuload > limit ))`.

Comment: @choroba Check update in decription please. Thanks.

Comment: Aside from the fact that `[[ $cpuload > $limit ]]` is a lexicographical comparison, hat are you expecting `s/.$//` to do, exactly? In regex, `.` means "any single character" - if you want to remove a trailing decimal you'd need `s/\..*$//` or `s/\.[0-9]*$//`

Comment: @steeldriver This last pipe remove last char from cpuload value which I get by `cut`, which is in this case `,` after value of cpuload `3.45, -> 3.45`. But I tried already with non-decimal value too, same situation.

Comment: Ah I see well then your issue is that bash only supports integer arithmetic. Anyhow you probably shouldn't rely on parsing the output of the `uptime` command since the date portion varies depending on whether the uptime is days / hours / minutes - it might be less fragile to grab the value from `/proc/loadavg` directly

Comment: see decsiption and **UPDATE 2**, but I am not sure why it is working now.

Comment: In addition to what the others said, notice that your decimal separator depends on environment variables like LC_NUMERIC or LC_ALL. For a German shell environment, you get `0,81`, for an English environment, `0.81`. Always set a well-defined environment when you parse the output of commands; set `LC_ALL=C` to avoid nasty surprises.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach here is doomed for a number of reasons.

First, even if you get the syntax correct for arithmetic comparison, i.e. either:

```
[ $cpuload -gt $limit ]
```

(POSIX shell compatible) or

```
[[ $cpuload -gt $limit ]]
```

(bash / ksh extended test) or

```
(( cpuload > limit ))
```

the bash shell only supports integer arithmetic, so you'd need to trim off any trailing decimal first, being mindful of your locale's numeric representation, [as mentioned by HuHa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340357/bash-if-decimal-is-greater-is-working-strange#comment2289210_1340357).

Note that when you used `[[ $cpuload > $limit ]]` that **is** a syntactically valid comparison in bash, however it will work "strangely", since it compares the RHS and LHS lexicographically, character-by-character. In particular,

```
$ [[ 3.0 > 10.0 ]] && echo greater || echo not greater
greater
```

because character `3` is lexicographically greater than character `1`; whereas

```
$ [[ 03.0 > 10.0 ]] && echo greater || echo not greater
not greater
```

because character `0` is lexicographically less than character `1`. The bottom line is that if you want to do floating point arithmetic in a bash script, you will need an external program such as `bc` or `awk` or `perl`.<sup>1</sup>

Second, the `uptime` output is intended for human readability, not machine parsing. In particular, the time format varies depending on the actual uptime, ex.:

(before reboot)

```
$ uptime
 10:38:50 up 26 days, 12:33,  4 users,  load average: 0.09, 0.04, 0.00
```

(after reboot)

```
$ uptime
 10:44:37 up 3 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.17, 0.33, 0.16
```

Attempting to tokenize it with `cut -d' '` is especially fragile, since it relies on exactly how much left-padding each of the fields has: it will fail if the number of days / hours / minutes / users rolls over from single to double digits for example.

Instead, I'd suggest reading the load average directly from `/proc/loadavg` - which is where `uptime` gets it from anyhow, as you can confirm with `strace`:

```
$ strace -etrace=openat uptime 2>&1 | tail -n 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/loadavg", O_RDONLY) = 4
 12:49:38 up  2:08,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.01, 0.00
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The format is simple whitespace separated fields that you can easily parse and test with `awk` for example:

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.52 0.58 0.59 1/5 3759

$ limit=10; awk -v limit="$limit" '$1+0 > limit {exit 1}' /proc/loadavg && echo "ok" || echo "overload"
   ok

$ limit=0.5; awk -v limit="$limit" '$1+0 > limit {exit 1}' /proc/loadavg && echo "ok" || echo "overload"
   overload
```

Notes:

1. You could of course switch to a shell that *does* support non-integer arithmetic, such as `ksh` or `zsh`.